# use PlaceDetectionApi to detect place get INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, google-places-api

I use google map to detect current place but get error
here is my code:

```
private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    guessCurrentPlace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .build();
}


private void guessCurrentPlace() {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result =
            Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            if (!likelyPlaces.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Request did not complete successfully
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                        likelyPlaces.getStatus().getStatusCode(), ServiceProviderActivity.this ,0).show();
                Logger.d(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + likelyPlaces.getStatus().toString());
                likelyPlaces.release();
                return;
            }
            PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood = likelyPlaces.get(0);
            String content = "";
            if (placeLikelihood != null && placeLikelihood.getPlace() != null &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName())) {
                content = "Most likely place: " + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() + "\n";
            }
            if (placeLikelihood != null) {
                content += "Percent change of being there: " + (int) (placeLikelihood.getLikelihood() * 100) + "%";
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

I always get the error, and the value of likelyPlaces is:
{status=Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}, attributions=null}

I add these in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and

```
<!-- PlacePicker also requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

and other uses-permissions needed.
Do anyone know why?

EDIT1:
In Google Developer Console, I get the API's statistics data, whit show all responses are "Client Error (4XX)"

EDIT2:
My mistake, generate KEY with release keystore but debug with debug keystore.
problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Place Detection API is returning INTERNAL_ERROR, i later discovers it was because of  new permission in Android.

i requested the permission and it works. i hope its help

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] { Android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  }, 2 );
}
```